# How to recursively iterate over Lists of Lists in JAVA 8

Tags: list, recursion, collections, java-8

I have a following scenario

```
 Object A has
 -- List<B>
 -- List<C> 
     -- Object A
```

Object A contains: `List<B>` and `List<C>`

I want to collect all objects of type 'B' in a List after traversal in a given object 'A'.

**Note:** `List<C>` may contain object 'A', so iteration becomes recursive.

```
I/P: Object A  = {List<B>,List<C>}
O/P: List<B>//list of all objects of type B
```

What is the best way to iterate over this and collect objects of type 'B' to a List in JAVA 8.

Thanks

Comment: Are we assuming that `list` is a `List<List<A>>` and `B extends A`?

Comment: You are going to have to recursively iterate over all the items in the root list then iterate over those items that are of type List.  Each iteration returns List<B> and you just combine one to the next.

Comment: And have you written some code so far?

Comment: apparently Java tag gets you lot of downvotes

Comment: Can the sublists have other sublists?

Comment: I have modified the post

Comment: Modified the post again to make it moee clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I don't understand is why it has to be done soly with Stream? Why don't you  just create a recursive function? And your `List<A>` definitely does not contain another `List<A>` and `List<B>`, your object `A` probably contains those two lists.

Here is a simple recursive method that should help you, but keep in mind that you did not really provide the code of A and B so we cannot really know:

```
    public List<B> getAllBs(List<A> aList) {
    return aList.stream()
                .map(a -> getAllBs(a))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private List<B> getAllBs(A someA) {
    List<B> returnList = new ArrayList<B>();
    returnList.addAll(someA.getListOfB());

    for(A otherA: someA.getListOfA()) {
        returnList.addAll(getAllBs(otherA);
    }

    return returnList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `list` is a `List<List<A>>` and `B extends A`, and you mean that any sub-list could have any amount of `B`s but you don't want `A`s:

```
List<A> allBs = list.stream() //Stream<List<A>>
                    .flatMap(l -> l.stream()) //Stream<A>
                    .filter(a -> a instanceof B) //Stream<A> containing only Bs
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()); //List<A> containing only Bs
```

Admittedly untested, because I'm working off many assumptions from a poor question.